# How can I combine the first two rows in 52 files as a header row and combine all the files in a single one in Power Query?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have 52 files with >50 columns. The first two rows in each of them are header rows, so they need to be combined into a single row and I want to combine them all into a single file.

There are some files with a different number of columns or different column names, so if PowerQuery identifies those, I can deal with them seperately.

The only way I can think of is opening each file, running a macro to combine the first two rows in all of the files, but is there a more efficient way to do that in Power query on all the files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the file has the same structure and you need to combine them, you can use the '[Load from Folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/folder)' option. You go through the load from folder options as normal and then select 'Combine & Transform Data'.

[image: Load from folder]

In the query editor, look for the 'Helper Queries'.

[image: Helper Query]

This query uses a selected example of the file, to determine metadata for the rest of the file loading. If you look at the 'Transform Sample File' you can add your in steps to combine the rows. It will apply any steps here to every file in the folder when loading.
You can then 'Use first row as headers' to promote you combined rows to the header. You may need to remove the automatically applied promoted headers step if Power Query has done that already.

Once that is done, it will combine the files into one table in Power Query. It is best to do this on a sample set of files to see it if works, then add in the rest of the files. For those files that are of different structures it can get a bit messy, so it would be best to create different folders for them and load them that way.

Comment: Thats interesting. Out of the 52, maybe 2-3 might have different structures. So I'm fine with dealing with them seperately as long as PowerQuery identifies them because without opening each file and counting the columns and making sure the headers are the same, I wouldn't be able to tell if the structure is the same.

For the transformation, would I just be transposing the dataset, combining the first two columns, then transposing again? That takes a really long time and I end up with 12000+ columns. Is there a better way for it?

Comment: If the column names are the same it will Union/Append them, not add them a new columns.

Comment: Is there a way to remove the first row two rows of files 2-52? After combining and promoting the header, I still have the header rows in the files I combined

Comment: If you have added the process to the Transform Sample File, it should apply them to the later files, and you should not have them in the dataset

Answer (score 0):

```
let Source = Folder.Files("C:\directory\subdirectory"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".xlsx")),

// get all data from all XLS files
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Name", "Content"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "GetFileData", each Excel.Workbook([Content],true)),
#"Expanded GetFileData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "GetFileData", {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Name"}, {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Sheet"}),
// filter for specific sheet
#"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded GetFileData", each ([Sheet] = "Sheet1")),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows1",{"Content", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind"}),

//demote, then combine first two rows of each column, then recombine with original data
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns","Top", each Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table.Transpose(Table.FirstN(Table.DemoteHeaders([Data]),2)),{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}})),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1" ,"Bottom", each Table.Transpose(Table.CombineColumns([Top] ,{"Column1", "Column2"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"))),
#"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2" ,"Data3", each Table.PromoteHeaders( [Bottom]  & Table.Skip(Table.DemoteHeaders([Data]),2))),

// expand all columns and remove extras
List = List.Union(List.Transform(#"Added Custom3"[Data3], each Table.ColumnNames(_))),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom3", "Data3", List,List),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Data",{"Data", "Top", "Bottom"})
in #"Removed Columns1"
```

This is how I'd do it

1. Opens all the xlsx files in the directory (Change extension and path as needed)
2. Reads in all columns on all tabs in each file
3. In each data table, combines first two rows of each column then combines with the
   data under that
4. Then expands all tables

Comment: Is there a way to manipulate that so I can specify a sheet? I've tried changing around the code myself but keep getting an error

Comment: changed to filter to sheet